# How to select more than 1 type with @ContentChildren in angular2

Tags: angular

Code:

```
    @Component({selector: 'item1', template: 'item1'})
    export class Item1Component {}    

    @Component({selector: 'item2', template: 'item2'})
    export class Item2Component {}

    @Component({selector: 'item-group', template: `
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    `})
    export class ItemGroupComponent {

        @ContentChildren(Item1Component)// <-- ?
        private items: QueryList<Item1Component>;

        ngAfterContentInit() {
           console.log('items', this.items);
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------
    <item-group>
       <item1></item1>
       <item2></item2>
    </item-group>
```

Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/jxoxWuuX0MAGym2irg0V?p=preview

Question: I can select Item1Component or Item2Component with @ContentChildren but how can i select both of types Item1Component and Item2Component in one QueryList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do here is adding an identifier to each sub elements in your input content:

```
<item-group>
  <item1 #i1></item1>
  <item2 #i2></item2>
</item-group>
```

and reference them by id into your `@ContentChildren`:

```
@ContentChildren('i1,i2')
private items: QueryList<any>;
```

In this case, you will have the two elements in your query list.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/zVurr55KI9kwoJPwGzDw?p=preview.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not supported if you pass the type of the component as argument. You can pass multiple template variable names though

```ts
@ContentChildren('item1,item2,item3')
```

or alternatively you can use the same template variable for all items and query them like

```ts
@ContentChildren('item')
```

Comment: where is the example?

Comment: Seems I forgot to post the link and I don't have it anymore.